# C++11: Preventing lambda scope capture bugs

Tags: c++11, lambda

In C++, in contrast to languages such as C#, it is possible to specify if or not enclosing scope variables shall be capture by value or by reference within a lambda expression. This leads to the undefined case in which it is possible to pass a lambda with enclosing scope captured by reference to a function that returns before invoking the lambda expression:

```
void test()
{
    int t = 1;
    enqueue_task([&]() { do_something(t); });
}
```

In this case, "t" will most likely be out of scope when that task specified by the lambda expression is scheduled for execution. This leads to ugly bugs, obviously.

MY solution would be a language feature like this:

```
template<class T>
void enqueue_task(T lambda)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lambda<T>::value || std::is_lambda_captured_by_value<T>::value,
        "The lambda expression is executed asynchronously and therefore capturing eclosing state via reference is forbidden.");

    // enqueue task for execution
}
```

To me, this would be a clean "non-invasive" extension that would allow middle-ware writers to protect their API from misuse. Of course it doesn't offer bullet-proof protection, since I still can pass a pointer to a stack object by value and probably much more. Anyway, code that would still silently cause undefined behavior when being passed by value will probably be by itself already questionable.

Is there something similar I can do that is already supported?

To me, a sane solution at the moment seems to simply NOT allow any lambda expression in deferred execution situations. For instance, an event handler should not be allowed to be of a lambda type. Which is easier said than done, since this also implies that I can't use std::function and would have to go back to good old function types.

An even better approach would be to introduce kind of a keyword, like:

```
void test()
{
    int t = 1;
    enqueue_task(deferred () { do_something(t); });
}
```

which would make sure that, by all mean a compiler can, the passed lambda function will be suitable for delayed execution, which means when its enclosing scope is gone.

I think C++11 has gone long way to make C++ programming safe. This lambda-thing is one of the few places where you are still pointing a gun at your feet. Its just a ticking timebomb.

Comment: "a sane solution at the moment seems to simply NOT allow any lambda expression in deferred execution situations." Then you lose the ability to form closures.

Comment: @JAB: Ofc, but I didn't mean not allow standard-wise, but rather API-wise. So if lambdas don't contribute to your API's usability and there is a potential that users may forget that your API calls lambdas deferred, then you should just not use lambdas for this API. An API should force correct usage.

Comment: True enough, but it's not like lambda expressions are the only way you can get the sort of issues you're worried about. What happens if the user passes a non-lambda function that does something messy involving out-of-scope references? Or, god forbid, raw pointers? The only way to truly force correct usage of the API is to prevent users from supplying any sort of input to it (and even without doing that, you could end up with false positives if you aren't careful about how you set up the constraints, where valid parameters are rejected because they aren't quite set up the way you require).

Comment: Note that C++14 apparently supports capture-by-move in lambdas, though, which may well be a (future) solution to your problem. http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/05/c14-lambdas-and-perfect-forwarding.html

Comment: I don't fully see how I could use this for my problem yet :P? Non lambda is not soo dangerous because people will be more careful (I hope). But I saw myself several times writing lambdas by reference which were called later -.-. Its just too easy to make mistakes there.

Comment: And I've found myself writing array/pointer accesses that turned out to have out-of-bounds edge cases and caused segfaults. The proper thing to do in C++, of course, is to use container classes like those from the STL, and you can ensure that sort of behavior in your API interface, but you can't stop a user from using unsafe array accesses in their own code just as you can't stop a user from not using one of the templated cast functions instead of raw casts when obtaining variables returned from your API, etc.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to the same question.  It occurred to me to use a wrapper object that is only enabled when you make a copy of it.  But that doesn't work, because it's still UB to access the wrapper to check the enabled flag if it's out of scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the remedy is to capture by value `[=]() {...}`.
When copying the actual object is not viable, it is usually beneficial to use it via a `shared_ptr`, which might offer cheaper copying, depending on the context, and would also allow you to share the ownership such that both the caller and the deferred lambda use it independently.

C++14 should have move-capture semantics, which would solve the performance problem of copying the object, when sharing is not needed.

Otherwise, passing by-ref is what you want. And like everything in C++, not just in lambdas, when you start passing pointers and references around, you need to be careful.

Comment: Okay I am marking this an anwser, even though JAB did say the thing earlier, but only as a comment :P.

Comment: @thesaint Note he said *some* of it. The important part here IMO is the capture-by-value; and where you need the same object, use shared_ptrs to it by value. shared_ptr can still be a bit expensive to copy in some scenarios because of atomic operations, which is why I mentioned that capture-by-move semantics is coming soon.

Comment: @thesaint this doesn't really answer the question. the question is Can we do something like static_assert is_lambda_captured_by_value? And the answer is, presumably, No we cannot. The closest I found was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890486/7098259