# Is there a way to prevent lambda capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm in the middle of a refactor of existing code that relies on lambdas. In the new version of the code I'd like to defer the calls into the lambdas, so I'd like to prevent any future users from accidentally capturing by reference, as well as use the compiler to find all the offending existing code.

Is this possible with c++11?

Comment: Nope. Anyone is free to write a lambda that captures by reference.

Comment: Why would you prevent that? Capture by reference can be really useful?

Comment: @Rerito: The main reason would be that you're going to store that lambda and call it later, at which time the reference may have become invalid. So you want to avoid anyone from passing you such a lambda. Then again, this is probably an XY question. Lambda's aren't the only type of functors, and the real problem is deciding which functors can be stored.

Comment: @MSalters Furthermore which state of the captured objects should be used when doing the callback? That's the questions pinned by Yakk in his answer actually. So yeah I agree with you: it sounds very XY-ish

Comment: @Rerito: Which state to use is trivial. If there's capture by reference (not copy), there is only one object _at most_ (zero after its lifetime ends). Therefore, there is only one state and no choice.

Comment: @MSalters that's not what I meant. By capturing by value, we make sure that when the callback will run, the captured object will be in the same state as when it was captured, ignoring potential updates. With a reference we avoid that but we have the burden of carefully managing object lifetime

Answer (score 1):

No.  And it wouldn't help much: once lifetimes exceed the current scope, you have to both capture by value *and* ensure the lifetime of all pointers or referred to (in any way) resources is managed.

An async callback is a fundamentally different beast than a sync callback, and the C++ type system cannot enforce safety here.

Even if resource lifetime issues where solved, the calling code was expecting the changes caused by the lambda to occur immediately, and now they don't.  Every use would have to be audited for the new pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> use the compiler to find all the offending existing code.

This is possible, but *non-trivial* using libtooling/clang plugin -- but probably not how you'd expect.

You can write a plugin that the compiler runs after it compiles all your code and that plugin can inspect the AST that clang builds while compiling your code.   You can traverse the AST to find lambdas and inspect the types of their capture lists.   It's pretty cool, but the documentation isn't great and it can be a time-consuming process.   Probably not worth it for a one-off project.

Comment: I think the plugin integration for clang is made through libtooling (which uses their internal C++ API IIRC). libclang is a (quite) stable C API to clang that allows you to toy with the AST in independant programs. That would definitely be doable with libclang, but as an external checking tool

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html - Do not use LibClang when you want full control over the Clang AST.   Use LibTooling/ClangPlugin when you want full control over the Clang AST.   I'll update the wording in my answer, as I didn't mean libclang.

Comment: And the doc sure isn't great. Too bad because it's a really powerful tool :(