# When are explicitly-named variable captures necessitated in the definition of a C++11 lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, scope, rvalue-reference

Up until now, when looking at [C++ lambda expressions in the `c++11` style](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), I’ve put all of them into two broad categories: capturing and non-capturing.

Non-capturing lambdas, while more restricted in how they can be written, are much more flexible in how they can be used – they can be [implicitly converted to analogous function-pointer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator_ret.28.2A.29.28params.29.28.29); they don’t encourage gratuitous `std::function<…>` usage, their implementation scope is [less likely to creep out and cause side-effect problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613295/298171), and so on.

A capturing lambda, however, can be written in a far broader manner. Admittedly, they don’t confer all those benefits I just mentioned. But the capturing lambda makes up for it with the great range of problems it can solve, by breaking out of the confines of the stack’s feed-forward function-call DAG with myriad forms of access to the surrounding scopes.

That’s as far as my understanding goes, however. When I am using capturing lambdas, I tend to explicitly reference-capture specific variables when there are between one and two variables I need:

```cpp
using lambda_t = std::function<std::add_pointer_t<void>(int)>;

lambda_t lambda_explicit = [&one, &another](int descriptor) {
    return ::mmap(nullptr, one, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, descriptor, another);
};
```

… if there are more than two, I prefer (out of equal parts syntactic OCD and laziness) to eschew explicitly named captures in favor of the reference-to-everything form:

```cpp
lambda_t lambda_everything = [&](int descriptor) {
    return ::mmap(nullptr, one, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, descriptor, another);
};
```

… which note that changing the form of the lambda’s captures does not alter anything obvious about the lambda’s type – the call signature is the same, for example. This is counterintuitive as it seems that [much of the way capturing works is vaguely specified and somewhat implementation-specific](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::Captures), sort of inversely proportionate to the detailed formal variety afforded by the capture expression (or is it a declaration? or a declaration list?… I am not sure) the full glory of which you’ll see, if you go to that last link and scroll down just a little bit.

I haven’t even touched the overarching majority of the possibilities – I almost always just do either:

1. No capturing at all;
2. One or two explicitly-named variables captured-by-reference; or
3. The indiscriminate capturing-by-reference of everything: `[&]`

What are the circumstances in which I should go out of the way to use one form of capturing over the other?

Which forms are special-case, and to be generally avoided? Which have tangible penalties – in performance, code size, potential UB, or anything else? Do any capture forms have tangible and/or easy benefits?

Comment: use what you need, otherwise this question is too broad imho

Comment: Do note that `[&]` is not capture everything.  It is capture everything used.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking to be honest. FWIW I usually share your approach, purely because I like to be explicit until it's too burdensome to be worthwhile. (Though I'm a fan of `[=]` in member functions too)

Comment: *"[..] don’t encourage gratuitous std::function<…> usage"*, you don't have to use `std::function`, you might simply use `auto` instead of your unneeded `lambda_t`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think the statement is assuming some context that hasn't been communicated. Like storing into a container. You can store (at runtime) function pointers into different lambdas with the same signature in a container, but you cannot do so for different capturing lambdas.

Comment: There is the obvious problem that capturing by reference prevents a lambda from being able to be called after the scope in which the referenced variables were created goes away. Any such call invites UB when the lambda attempts to use the now invalid reference in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the circumstances in which I should go out of the way to use one form of capturing over the other?

When you are confined to using a stateless function, then captures are not an option, and you're confined to 1. This typically the case when registering a callback into a C language API.

When you want to move an object into a capture, you must move it into a named capture and are thus confined to 2. This is not possible in C++11 though; you need the generalised lambda captures from C++14. Generalised captures are also useful for mutable lambdas with initial state that doesn't need to be communicated to the outside (unless explicitly by returning).

Furthermore, when you wish to capture some set of variables by value and another set by reference, you can capture at most one set by default, and have to capture at least one set explicitly. That said, this is probably a special case. I don't recall ever having needed this.

I don't think there's ever a necessity to use the default capture, but it can save a lot of redundant typing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use named captures for the same reason I don't like global variables. It gives scope to the lambda code.

It very quickly becomes impossible to audit the code if there are many variables and many lambdas accessing just some of the variables with unnamed syntax. OK, if you have a small function with 3 local variables, then it is easy to accept that a lambda can see all three variables, but if you have 10 locals, you will waste time when revisiting the code trying to understand which three variables the lambda actually modifies.